# Direct execution of the data

Tags: c++

What is the best approach to make my program to execute the data. Say, I wrote the (so-called) compiler for **x86_64** machine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

struct compiler
{

    void op() const { return; }

    template< typename ...ARGS >
    void op(std::uint8_t const _opcode, ARGS && ..._tail)
    {
        code_.push_back(_opcode);
        return op(std::forward< ARGS >(_tail)...);
    }

    void clear() { code_.clear(); }

    long double operator () () const
    {
        // ?
    }

private :

    std::vector< std::uint8_t > code_;

};

int main()
{
    compiler compiler_; // long double (*)();
    compiler_.op(0xD9, 0xEE); // FLDZ
    compiler_.op(0xC3);       // ret
    std::cout << compiler_() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I don't know how to implement `operator ()` correctly. I suspect, that I must put all the contents of `code_` into contiguous memory chunk and then cast to `long double (*)();` and call this. But there is some difficulties:

- Should I use `VirtualProtect(Ex)` (+ `FlushInstructionCache`) on Windows? And something similar on Linux?
- What is the container, that reliably places the bytes in the memory in proper manner (i.e. one by one)? And also allows to get the pointer to memory chunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to allocate the code as executable [using VirtualAlloc with "executable" flag in Windows, and mmap using "MAP_EXECUTABLE" as one of the flags]. It's probably a lot easier to allocate a large region of this kind of memory, and then have a "allocation function" for your content. You could possibly use virtualprotect and whatever the corresponding function is in Linux, but I'd say that allocating as executable in the first place is a better choice. I don't believe you need to flush instruction cache it the memory is already allocated as executable - certainly not on x86 at least - and since your instructions are x86 instructions, I guess that's a fair limitation.

Second, you'll need to make something like a function pointer to your code. SOmething like this should do it:

```
typedef void (*funcptr)(void); 

funcptr f = reinterpret_cast<funcptr>(&code_[0]);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: So I can use some STL container with my own allocator, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. And like I said, you don't want to be calling mmap/VirtualAlloc inside each allocation call - allocate a "chunk" of memory, and dole out little pieces of that. However, I would consider the option of simply having a large(enough) lump of codespace, and simply tracking what's used and not in sections of, say, 4, 8 or 16 bytes, with a bitmap of "this is used" - or something of that sort.